# Ignoring Disabled Group Members in LDAP Java Query

Tags: java, ldap

I have a java ldap query where I pull users that exist in a group. However, I now need to filter out disabled accounts. I have added a user filter, but that does not seem to pull back any members at all. Any help is appreciated.

Below is my current java ldap query.

```
private LdapContext getTM1users(MbElement parser) throws FileNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException, MbException, NamingException
{
    LdapContext ctx = null;
    MbElement start = null;
    Attributes attrs = null;
    NamingEnumeration answer = null;
    String group = null;
    String location = null;

    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "Factory");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "UserID");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Password");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldapURL");

    ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
    constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String[] attrIDs = {"sAMAccountName"};
    constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);

    Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    ht.put("Agent_Comm", "Agent_Comm");
    ht.put("Elec_Finance", "Elec_Finance");
    ht.put("Freight", "Freight");
    ht.put("Vids", "Vids");

    Set<String> keys = ht.keySet();

    for(String key : keys)
    {
        group = ht.get(key);
        location = key;

        answer = ctx.search("DC=ads,DC=abc,DC=com", "memberOf=CN=" + group + ",OU=ADM,OU=ABC,DC=ads,DC=abc,DC=com (&(objectclass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))", constraints);
        while (answer.hasMore()) 
        {
            attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
            start = parser.createElementAsFirstChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME, "user", null);
            start.createElementAsFirstChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "userid",attrs.get("sAMAccountName").toString().trim());
            start.createElementAsFirstChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "location", location);               
        }
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

Comment: Just add another attribute value test to the filter.

Comment: Thanks I tried that, however I was not able to pull back any members although they exist. I will update the question. Thanks

Comment: You really should add "userAccountControl=*)" to the conjunction.  Also, memberOf refers to a DN, so you can't search for the RDN "CN=Freight" - it must be the full DN.

Comment: Marabu, you are saying I am able to have two "userAccountControl"s filters?

Comment: (&(memberOf=CN=" + memberOf + ",OU=ADM,OU=ABC,DC=ads,DC=abc,DC=com)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))  This works.